# How long before a bad alignment will have an affect on tyres?

Tags: alignment

If I travel a short distance day 20 miles with a bad alignment, is that likely to cause any significant  tyres wear or is it only over hundreds of miles etc after which it will start noticeably wearing due to the bad alignment? Basically over what sort of distances will tyres wear due to bad alignment such that it is significant or noticeable?

I know one should still get it done for safety reasons, but I’m just wondering about distance in this question though feel free to add any other relevant issues.

Comment: Because we have nothing by which we can judge misalignment of your vehicle, it is difficult to tell how fast it can wear. However, in my experience, assuming a vehicle which doesn't appear to be significantly misaligned, a single 20 mile drive shouldn't cause undue wear. However, I wouldn't recommend driving that far regularly or repeatedly, and as you have already noted, you should get it fixed.

Comment: Depends on how "bad" the alignment is.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to give a specific answer to this question without knowing how "bad" the bad alignment is. And, what condition your tires are in right now.

A **really really** bad alignment could certainly destroy already-worn tires within tens of miles. But that kind of issue is likely only possible with severe suspension damage. If you're talking about a more typical problem, 20 miles is almost certainly not going to be an issue - minor alignment issues may take hundreds or thousands of miles to even make a small impact on tire wear, much less wear a tire to the point of being destructive.

Keep in mind that "bad alignment" is a usually a symptom of another problem, not a problem in and of itself. In other words, if your alignment is bad, it is often because there is a failed or worn component in your suspension - i.e. a ball joint or tie rod end that's loose because it's worn out.